# Why is my motherboard temperature a constant arbitrary number?

Tags: motherboard

checked with Piriform Speccy.

[image]

checked with open hardware monitor

[image]

checked with hardware sensor monitor(this one shows different statistics)

[image]

Comment: You could also try [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php). It would be insteresting so see it this gives different results.

Comment: @munish Try looking at the sensors in the CPU itself rather than the motherboard sensors (which are [known to be wrong or implementation-specific](http://superuser.com/q/930833/6887), or even [entirely missing in some cases](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hwmon/nct6775)).  Can you post a larger screenshot of what you get in Open Hardware Monitor?  The temperature readings under the CPU itself (not the motherboard) should contain the most accurate reading.

Comment: here's screenshot([sensor](http://i.imgur.com/zBZc9pF.jpg) and [system summary](http://i.imgur.com/mHBDlQZ.jpg) ) from HWiNFO64.gives more details than any others i found.

Comment: [more](http://codeshare.io/UnkcX) info in html format

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your motherboard is not at 123'c. The application is reading a sensor that does not exist, or is reading data in a format it doesn't understand properly.

Not all motherboards have the same number of sensors, and not all sensor chips have all inputs connected. Sensors that are not connected will often give imaginary readings, whether that be zero, 123'c, 65535'c or any other temperature. It is also not unknown for negative temperatures, e.g. -127'c to be reported as well for unconnected sensors. The actual value used as "null" or "no reading" is specific to the driver and sensor chip in question.

Try to update to the latest drivers in order to fix sensor detection issues: [Intel NUC Kit D54250WYK](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/76977/Intel-NUC-Kit-D54250WYK)

Comment: I went into bios everything seems normal(mother board aroud 47 to 48 degrees) .and just now i downloaded another software called HWiNFO64.this one seems to give me correct readings when i open the sensor status tab.

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe you were watching in the wrong place, but i see clear an Intel Motherboard.

Comment: As @Ramhound said, we are here to learn and share, let the offensive things to another kind of places. Ramhound usually prefer to say something in comment first than give a bad answer.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq - I appreciate the feedback.  I am going to remove my all comments except this one, since my concerns with the answer, were addressed by an edit to it.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia - I appreciate you pointing out my error.  I was looking at the wrong field.

Comment: Here's another question where the CPU temperature was 123'c. [High CPU temperatures (123C)](http://superuser.com/q/386155). Coincidence?

Comment: Hmm.Thats sounds like more good info.thanks for the link

Comment: @DavidPostill: Nope, not coincidence. Causal relationship :) Both boards have the same monitoring chip - Nuvoton NCT6776F - so more likely than not, 123'c is the "default" temperature this chip outputs for any unconnected sensor.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not the 123 degrees Celsius number is real, the 15.79 volts for the +12V power bus is rather concerning.  I would recommend you go back into your bios and see if it agrees that the voltage is 15.  If so, power off your computer at once, as this may indicate a faulty power supply or motherboard.  If your power supply is really so far off, it's at least possible that the 123 degrees reading is real.

Comment: Eh, my board reports 11.4 12V inside Windows, but 12.00 in BIOS and Corsair Link (USB PSU w/ direct monitoring). His reading could be equally meaningless.

Comment: Sure, but it's not _obviously_ meaningless like 99.99V would be, so it's worth looking into.

Comment: Outside 5% on any rail 99% of motherboards will shut down immediately for protection.

Comment: Oh, interesting.