# Identifying temperaturs of sensors output

Tags: linux, temperature, sensors, lm-sensors

I need some help with interpreting the output of the sensors command. I use it together with watch to have updated live temperatures.

Part of the output is this:

```
f71882fg-isa-0a00
Adapter: ISA adapter
+3.3V:        +3.34 V  
in1:          +1.14 V  (max =  +2.04 V)
in2:          +0.93 V  
in3:          +0.69 V  
in4:          +0.95 V  
in5:          +1.09 V  
in6:          +0.89 V  
3VSB:         +3.33 V  
Vbat:         +3.26 V  
fan1:        2013 RPM
fan2:        1144 RPM
fan3:           0 RPM  ALARM
fan4:           0 RPM  ALARM
temp1:        +50.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, hyst = +81.0°C)
                       (crit = +100.0°C, hyst = +96.0°C)  sensor = transistor
temp2:        +28.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, hyst = +81.0°C)
                       (crit = +100.0°C, hyst = +96.0°C)  sensor = transistor
temp3:          FAULT  (high = +70.0°C, hyst = +68.0°C)
                       (crit = +85.0°C, hyst = +83.0°C)  sensor = transistor
```

I just wonder what these last three temperatures are?
Also the temp3 sometimes jumps from FAULT to +127°C (which is quite critical) and back.

Couldn't find any exact answer yet.

My actual problem is that my machine (with fedora 22 and gnome) freezes from time to time after a short time after booting. I guess the high temperatures these days around here are causing it.

**UPDATE**
Here is some extra information on my machine:

```
H/W path                 Device      Class       Description
============================================================
                                     system      MS-7345 (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
/0                                   bus         MS-7345
/0/0                                 memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/4                                 processor   Core 2 Duo (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
/0/4/5                               memory      128KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                               memory      8MiB L2 cache
/0/f                                 memory      4GiB System Memory
/0/f/0                               memory      2GiB DIMM SDRAM Synchronous
/0/f/1                               memory      2GiB DIMM SDRAM Synchronous
/0/f/2                               memory      DIMM [empty]
/0/f/3                               memory      DIMM [empty]
/0/100                               bridge      82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller
/0/100/1                             bridge      82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express PCI Express Root Port
/0/100/1/0                           display     GK106 [GeForce GTX 660]
/0/100/1/0.1                         multimedia  GK106 HDMI Audio Controller
/0/100/1a                            bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
/0/100/1a/1              usb3        bus         UHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1a.1                          bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
/0/100/1a.1/1            usb4        bus         UHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1a.7                          bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
/0/100/1a.7/1            usb1        bus         EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1a.7/1/3          scsi6       storage     STOR.E ALU 2S
/0/100/1a.7/1/3/0.0.0    /dev/sdb    disk        500GB SCSI Disk
/0/100/1a.7/1/3/0.0.0/1  /dev/sdb1   volume      465GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1b                            multimedia  82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                            bridge      82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1
/0/100/1c.4                          bridge      82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5
/0/100/1c.4/0                        storage     88SE6121 SATA II / PATA Controller
/0/100/1c.5                          bridge      82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6
/0/100/1c.5/0            enp4s0      network     RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1d                            bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
/0/100/1d/1              usb5        bus         UHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d/1/2                        input       Microsoft
/0/100/1d.1                          bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
/0/100/1d.1/1            usb6        bus         UHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d.1/1/1                      input       USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
/0/100/1d.2                          bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
/0/100/1d.2/1            usb7        bus         UHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d.3                          bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
/0/100/1d.3/1            usb8        bus         UHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d.7                          bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
/0/100/1d.7/1            usb2        bus         EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1e                            bridge      82801 PCI Bridge
/0/100/1f                            bridge      82801IR (ICH9R) LPC Interface Controller
/0/100/1f.2                          storage     82801IR/IO/IH (ICH9R/DO/DH) 4 port SATA Controller [IDE mode]
/0/100/1f.3                          bus         82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller
/0/100/1f.5                          storage     82801I (ICH9 Family) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode]
/0/1                     scsi2       storage     
/0/1/0.0.0               /dev/sda    disk        1TB WDC WD10EZEX-00B
/0/1/0.0.0/1             /dev/sda1   volume      500MiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2             /dev/sda2   volume      931GiB Linux LVM Physical Volume partition
/0/2                     scsi3       storage
/0/2/0.0.0               /dev/cdrom  disk        DVDRAM GH20NS15
/1                       virbr0-nic  network     Ethernet interface
```

Comment: It would help if you identified your PC and motherboard ...

Comment: If you have the ability to run a different tool, that would help also, recent experience has taught me how these type of tools deal with not existance sensors are different.

Comment: Sometimes `lm-sensors` output doesn't match up to what sensors you actually have. See this recent question for related info (though on Windows the principle is the same) http://superuser.com/questions/936817/why-is-my-motherboard-temperature-a-constant-arbitrary-number; and the accepted answer there: *"Your application is reading a sensor that does not exist, or is reading data in a format it doesn't understand properly."*

Comment: So the +127°C might be meaningless?

Comment: yes. the word 'FAULT' is indicating that reads off the sensor are not functioning correctly, so no output from that sensor will be trustworthy. Additionally the value 127 is also suspicious (7 bits of contigious 1's) further leading us to believe that the result is abherent. Non-functional sensors report odd (and usually impossible) things. numbers like 0, 127, 255, etc should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a little bis less confused now. :P